How To Get Audio To Auto-Start in Expo Audio
I am a somewhat beginner coder using Expo-Av.For this particular project, I  would like the audio to start immediately after the page loads as well as loop if possible. My code is as follows:
const Music = require('./assets/sounds/MellowMusic.mp3');

export default function App() {

  const [Loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const sound = useRef( new Audio.Sound());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    LoadAudio();
  }, []);

  const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync({
      });

      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === false) {
          sound.current.playAsync();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const PauseAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync ();
        if (result.isLoaded) {
          if (result.isPlaying === true) {
            sound.current.pauseAsync();
         }
        }
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  const LoadAudio = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync ();
    if (checkLoading.isLoaded === false) {
      try {
        const result = await sound.current.loadAsync(Music, {}, true);
        if (result.isLoaded === false) {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log('Error In Loading Audio');
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
         setLoaded(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } else{
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <View style = {styles.buttons}>
      <Pressable style ={styles.play} onPress={PlayAudio}>
         <Image source = {require('./assets/images/PlayButton.png')}></Image>
       </Pressable>
      <Pressable style = {styles.pause} onPress={PauseAudio}>
         <Image source = {require('./assets/images/PauseButton.png')}></Image>
      </Pressable>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

I have tried adding "shouldPlay" "shouldPlay:true", "shouldLoop" and "shouldLoop:true" to the playAudio const to no avail.
